# How can I use cache in a asp.net (vb.net framework 2) class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a method, in a class, for retrieving some data from mssql database. I use this in many pages and web handlers depending on user's permission. I don't always want get data from database and need to use the advantage of caching. I am using vb.net framework 2 as my client and don't want to change it. I tried in many ways, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me...

My last try was this:

```
Dim myDataSet As New DataSet
myDataSet = CType(Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("myData"), DataSet)

If myDataSet Is Nothing Then
    myDataSet = GetData("select * from Table")
    Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("myData", myDataSet, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), TimeSpan.Zero)
    'End If
End If
```

This is one of the methods from a class (testClass.vb), Any suggestions please...

Comment: Maybe if you expand on what exactly "didn't work" means in terms of symptoms, people might be able offer suggestions.

Comment: What method are you executing this code in?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to expand, I used this class in a web handler and some normal aspx page, I am testing it in web handler and calling this method to display the data. I expected the result from cache second time, but it goes into "if condition" (means there is no cached dataset), am I using the correct way to store data set in cache? I used this "Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("myData", myDataSet, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), TimeSpan.Zero)"

Answer (score 0):

You should check Cache value for Nothing before trying to assign it to DataSet, something like

```
Dim myDataSet As DataSet

If HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("myData") Is Nothing

    myDataSet = GetData("select * from Table")
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("myData", myDataSet, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), TimeSpan.Zero)

Else

    myDataSet = HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("myData") 

End If
```